# MVC Delete record but how to code this in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a beginner of MVC3 with ASP.Net (C#) but I don't get the next situation to delete a record.

I have a View that ask the user to confirm delete a item (record). As code I have this to initialize the view:

```
public ActionResult KeywordsDelete(Guid id)
{
    _db = new BlaContext();
    return _db.SearchTerms.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).First();
}
```

But when confirmed, then I have the next code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KeywordsDelete(Guid id)
{
    _db = new BlaContext();
    var term = _db.SearchTerms.Where(x => x.id == id).First();
    _db.SearchTerms.Remove(term);
    _db.SaveChanges();
     return View("Keywords", _db.SearchTerms.ToList());
 }
```

Building is not possible because the signature of this method is already exists (same parameters and method name).

So I don't get how to delete a record in this situation. The view is created with a default Scaffold template (delete).

Comment: _db = new BlaContext(); - this line is in two controllers, there is the misteke

Comment: @evgeniy.labusnkiy: Why? They will be called on separate request, so there won't be a problem.

Comment: @evgeniy.labusnkiy How do you mean? In the second Action (with HttpPost), the _db is null then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your post function another additional parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KeywordsDelete(Guid id, FormCollection collection)
{
    _db = new BlaContext();
    var term = _db.SearchTerms.Where(x => x.id == id).First();
    _db.SearchTerms.Remove(term);
    _db.SaveChanges();
     return View("Keywords", _db.SearchTerms.ToList());
 }
```

But your GET Action should also return a View not a data object, I think.

```
public ActionResult KeywordsDelete(Guid id)
{
    _db = new BlaContext();
    return View(_db.SearchTerms.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).First());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So what I understand is that FormCollection most of all is add to the parameters list of the method in these situations as Insert,Edit and Delete?

Comment: In this special case, yes. Normaly you would use ModelBinding for create and edit POST Actions like `public ActionResult Edit(ModelType model)` and your GET Action would be `public ActionResult Edit(int id)` or so.

Answer (score 5):

I found an alternative solution to this problem while reading up on MVC. Check out: [Improving the Details and Delete Methods](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/improving-the-details-and-delete-methods)

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id = 0)
{
    // Delete stuff...
}
```

This will route the action Delete to the method DeleteConfirmed.

Comment: Nice! Much more elegant than adding an unnecessary parameter.