# how to delete a record from the list using id MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, model-view-controller, model

I am trying to use a list that keeps records of students with add,edit and delete option. In my delete option I have some difficulty regarding how to use the delete button on that view to delete that entity with the given id.

My Delete view

```
@model Task.Models.Students

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Delete</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
    <div>
        <h4>Students</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)  
            </dt>
            <dd>


 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addon)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Addon)
            </dd>

        </dl>

        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" onclick="redirectOnClick()" /> |
                <a href="javascript:history.back()">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        }
        <script>
            function redirectOnClick() {
                alert("Done!");
            }
            </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Delete function from HOMECONTROLLER page that gives form with already filled data that I want to delete

```
  public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var del = values.Find(data => data.Id == id);

            return View("Delete",del);
        }
```

I'm having an issue with how to use delete button to delete that record as I am a beginner in this field.

Thankyou!

Comment: “This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Delete record but how to code this in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935132/mvc-delete-record-but-how-to-code-this-in-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the built in scaffolding in Visual Studio, and create a controller for an entity in entity framework, Visual Studio will create 2 controller methods for the delete: a `GET` that loads the data of the to-be deleted record into the view (so that you can review and confirm), and a `POST` to commit the deletion.

In your code above, you are looking at the first one. In the resulting view, you should have an 'are you sure'-type button at the bottom of the view to call the actual deletion.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-details-and-delete-methods